# Set the "realpath cache size"

Tags: php

One of my extensions asks me to set the realpath_cache_size to a minimum of 512k. So do i have to set it inside of the .htaccess like:

```
realpath_cache_size = 512k
```

And what are the consequences for the whole site, is it ok or too high? I don´t understand this cache size.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The size can be change in php.ini file:

The line below determines the size of the realpath cache to be used by PHP.

realpath_cache_size = 16k

Here is more info about it from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-size

This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.

Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use this directive it had to be enabled at compile time by using --enable-memory-limit in the configure line. This compile-time flag was also required to define the functions memory_get_usage() and memory_get_peak_usage() prior to 5.2.1.

When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used.
See also: max_execution_time.

Performance Tuning

Performance Tuning
Name    Default Changeable  Changelog
realpath_cache_size "16K"   PHP_INI_SYSTEM  Available since PHP 5.1.0.
realpath_cache_ttl  "120"   PHP_INI_SYSTEM  Available since PHP 5.1.0.
Here's a short explanation of the configuration directives.

realpath_cache_size integer
Determines the size of the realpath cache to be used by PHP. This value should be increased on systems where PHP opens many files, to reflect the quantity of the file operations performed.

The size represents the total number of bytes in the path strings stored, plus the size of the data associated with the cache entry. This means that in order to store longer paths in the cache, the cache size must be larger. This value does not directly control the number of distinct paths that can be cached.

The size required for the cache entry data is system dependent.

realpath_cache_ttl integer
Duration of time (in seconds) for which to cache realpath information for a given file or directory. For systems with rarely changing files, consider increasing the value.

Comment: Did you type all that?

Comment: Your answer will be misleading to many people. The answer should not include information about memory_limit configuration because it is not directly related to the question.

Comment: I agree with what @DanielV. said. It makes things very confusing to be talking about memory_limit documentation.